# Visual C++ _snprintf setting errno to ERANGE

Tags: c++, c++11

I just noticed that when my code is compiled with Visual C++ 2013, the _snprintf function sets errno to ERANGE (Result too large) when the destination buffer is too small. This doesn't seem to be documented:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2ts7cx93.aspx

I expect a return value of -1 (and so did the code), but not any meddling with errno. Is this behavior docuemnted elsewhre, and is it possibly a recent change? Does the C++11 standard (which I believe adds snprintf) have anything to say about this?

Comment: The documentation you linked mentions that it sets errno.

Comment: @KennyOstrom it's more complicated than that and it definitely doesn't mention setting `errno` to `ERANGE`.

Comment: Yes, but it does not mention a case where it would be set to ERANGE. And as the answer by @tomasz-sodzawiczny below quotes from the standard "provided the use of  errno is not documented in the description of the function". This function does document the use of errno, and yet sets it to something undocumented, which I would read as a breach of the standard.

Comment: My takeaway from this is that I shouldn't be surprised that a vendor-specific function changes behavior, and stick to the standard library as much as possible. Too bad snprintf isn't in the subset that Microsoft chose to implement (not by Visual C++ 2013, at least). Full C99 support would be nice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does the C++11 standard (which I believe adds snprintf) have anything
>   to say about this?

Yes, the behaviour you described would be correct for `snprintf`.
After the C standard (referred to by C++ standard):

> (7.21.6.5.3.) The `snprintf` function returns the number of characters that would
>   have been written had `n` been sufficiently large, not counting the
>   terminating null character, **or a negative value if an encoding error
>   occurred**. Thus, the null-terminated output has been completely written
>   if and only if the returned value is nonnegative and less than `n`.

As for the `errno` - the function description says nothing about it, so this applies:

> (7.5.3.) The value of `errno` may be set to nonzero by a library
>   function call whether or not there is an error,  provided the use of
>   `errno` is not documented in the description of the function in this
>   International Standard.

Comment: Thank you. I conclude from this that the function is in error - it makes mention of errno in the documentation, yet sets it to a value that it does not document, which I would consider a breach of (7.5.3.). OTOH, Microsoft is careful to call out that their functions are non-standard (by adding the leading underscore), so it shouldn't come as too much of a surprise.

Comment: The (7.5.3.) applies to standard functions only, other functions might behave differently - I would not consider it a breach. I think they forgot to include the information about `ERANGE` in the documentation - you can write to them so they can fix that.

Comment: also - this answer relates to standard `snprintf` only, there are more differences between `snprintf` and Microsoft's `_snprintf` (terminal '\0', etc.).

Answer (score 1):

The function is in compliance with the standard.  As mentioned by Tomasz, the complete text of 7.5.3 says " The value of errno may be set to nonzero by a library function call whether or not there is an error, provided the use of  errno is not documented in the description of the function **in this International Standard**".  The use of errno is not documented in the description of sprintf in the Standard, ergo the library is free to set errno to a non-zero value.  Whether Microsoft documents something or not in their documentation is **not** covered by 7.5.3.

Comment: Not only that, but no function called `_snprintf` is documented in the standard.